# How do I fake certain south migration in django tests(in a custom test runner)?

Tags: python, django, django-south

My project uses a third-party app, that doesn't use south for migrations.
We wrote a data migration, that depends on that 3d-party app and as a result our tests are now failing.

So I would like to customise our test runner, to fake certain migration, but I can't find the correct place or function to override to call fake the migration.

Can anyone point me where should I do that?

Comment: I'm not sure the problem is what you're saying it is. There shouldn't be any problem using non-south-managed apps in a data migration. After all, non of Django's core apps are south-enabled and I use them all the time in migrations.

Can you post some examples of your migrations, and what errors you're getting?

Comment: The problem is that data-migration depends on an app, that is not managed by south. So I get this error during test db creation: 'Cannot resolve keyword 'social_auth' into field' (3d party app is social_auth btw)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set:

```
SOUTH_TESTS_MIGRATE = False
```

In your settings, South migrations will not be run as part of your tests instead the database will be created according to whats defined in your models as a regular syncdb.

This will also speed up your tests.

Comment: I'll consider this. I know about the option, but turning off all migration testing altogether seems like an overkill for the problem though.

Comment: Well your tests shouldn't really be about your migrations imo. Your tests are for your your code base, why would you wanna run migrations for tests?